# Constraining for each observation with same ID

Tags: stata

I've got a dataset where I've been working a while to clean it up from wide to long format.

We're following about 1.000 patients with 1-5 aneurysms (can have more than 1 aneurysm) and some or all are treated with different available treatments. The patient can have two aneurysms where one is treated with treatment A and the other is treated with treatment B.

Here's an example of the data:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str32 record_id float treatmentChoice_ byte(treatment_1 treatment_3) float aneurysm_id
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" . . . 1
"007128de18ce5cb1635b8f27c5435ff3" . . . 2
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" . 2 . 1
"00abd7bdb6283dd0ac6b97271608a122" . . . 2
"0142103f84693c6eda416dfc55f65de1" . 1 . 1
"0142103f84693c6eda416dfc55f65de1" . . . 2
"0153826d93a58d7e1837bb98a3c21ba8" . . . 1
"0153826d93a58d7e1837bb98a3c21ba8" . . . 2
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" . 1 . 1
"01c729ac4601e36f245fd817d8977917" . . . 2
"01dd90093fbf201a1f357e22eaff6b6a" . . . 1
"01dd90093fbf201a1f357e22eaff6b6a" . 1 . 2
"0208e14dcabc43dd2b57e2e8b117de4d" . . . 1
"0208e14dcabc43dd2b57e2e8b117de4d" . 1 . 2
"0210f575075e5def7ffa77530ce17ef0" . . . 1
"0210f575075e5def7ffa77530ce17ef0" . . . 2
"022cc7a9397e81cf58cd9111f9d1db0d" . . . 1
"022cc7a9397e81cf58cd9111f9d1db0d" . . . 2
"02afd543116a22fc7430620727b20bb5" . 2 . 1
"02afd543116a22fc7430620727b20bb5" . . . 2
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" . . . 1
"0303ef0bd5d256cca1c836e2b70415ac" . 1 . 2
"041b2b0cac589d6e3b65bb924803cf1a" . . . 1
"041b2b0cac589d6e3b65bb924803cf1a" . . . 2
"0536317a2bbb936e85c3eb8294b076da" . . . 1
"0536317a2bbb936e85c3eb8294b076da" . 1 . 2
"06161d4668f217937cac0ac033d8d199" . . . 1
"06161d4668f217937cac0ac033d8d199" . . . 2
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" . . 1 1
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" . . . 2
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" . . . 3
"065e151f8bcebb27fabf8b052fd70566" . . . 4
"07196414cd6bf89d94a33e149983d102" . . . 1
"07196414cd6bf89d94a33e149983d102" . . . 2
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" . . . 1
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" . . . 2
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" . . . 3
"0721c38f8275dab504fc53aebcc005ce" 1 . . 4
"07bef516d53279a3f5e477d56d552a2b" . . . 1
"07bef516d53279a3f5e477d56d552a2b" . 2 . 2
"08678829b7e0ee6a01b17974b4d19cfa" . . . 1
"08678829b7e0ee6a01b17974b4d19cfa" . . . 2
"08bb6c65e63c499ea19ac24d5113dd94" . . . 1
"08bb6c65e63c499ea19ac24d5113dd94" . . . 2
"08f036417500c332efd555c76c4654a0" . . . 1
"08f036417500c332efd555c76c4654a0" . . . 2
"090c54d021b4b21c7243cec01efbeb91" . . . 1
"090c54d021b4b21c7243cec01efbeb91" . . . 2
"09166bb44e4c5cdb8f40d402f706816e" . . . 1
"09166bb44e4c5cdb8f40d402f706816e" . 1 . 2
"0930159addcdc35e7dc18812522d4377" . . . 1
"0930159addcdc35e7dc18812522d4377" . . . 2
"096844af91d2e266767775b0bee9105e" . . . 1
"096844af91d2e266767775b0bee9105e" . 2 . 2
"09884af1bb9d59803de0c74d6df57c23" . . . 1
"09884af1bb9d59803de0c74d6df57c23" . 2 . 2
"09e03748da35e9d799dc5d8ddf1909b5" . . . 1
"09e03748da35e9d799dc5d8ddf1909b5" . . . 2
"0a4ce4a7941ff6d1f5c217bf5a9a3bf9" . . . 1
"0a4ce4a7941ff6d1f5c217bf5a9a3bf9" . . . 2
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" 4 . . 1
"0a5db40dc58e97927b407c9210aab7ba" . . . 2
"0a73c992955231650965ed87e3bd52f6" . . . 1
"0a73c992955231650965ed87e3bd52f6" . 2 . 2
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" 1 . 2 1
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" . . . 2
"0a84ab77fff74c247a525dfde8ce988c" . . . 3
"0af333ae400f75930125bb0585f0dcf5" . . . 1
"0af333ae400f75930125bb0585f0dcf5" . . . 2
"0af73334d9d2166191f3385de48f15d2" . 1 . 1
"0af73334d9d2166191f3385de48f15d2" . . . 2
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" . . . 1
"0b341ac8f396a8cdb88b7c658f66f653" . . . 2
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" . 1 . 1
"0b35cf4beb830b361d7c164371f25149" . . . 2
"0b3e110c9765e14a5c41fadcc3cfc300" . . . 1
"0b6681f0f441e69c26106ab344ac0733" . . . 1
"0b6681f0f441e69c26106ab344ac0733" . . . 2
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" 4 . . 1
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" . . . 2
"0b8d8253a8415275dbc2619e039985bb" . . . 3
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" . 2 . 1
"0b92c26375117bf42945c04d8d6573d4" . . . 2
"0ba961f437f43105c357403c920bdef1" . . . 1
"0ba961f437f43105c357403c920bdef1" . . . 2
"0bb601fabe1fdfa794a5272408997a2f" . . . 1
"0bb601fabe1fdfa794a5272408997a2f" . . . 2
"0c75b36e91363d596dc46bd563c3f5ef" . 1 . 1
"0c75b36e91363d596dc46bd563c3f5ef" . . . 2
"0d461328a3bae7164ce7d3a10f366812" . . . 1
"0d461328a3bae7164ce7d3a10f366812" . 2 . 2
"0d4cc4eb459301a804cbef22914f44a3" . 1 . 1
"0d4cc4eb459301a804cbef22914f44a3" . . . 2
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" . . . 1
"0d4e29e11bb94e922112089f3fec61ef" . 1 . 2
"0d513c74d667f55c8f4a9836c304149c" . 1 . 1
"0d513c74d667f55c8f4a9836c304149c" . . . 2
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" . . . 1
"0da25de126bb3b3ee565eff8888004c2" . 1 . 2
"0db9ae1f2201577f431b7603d0819fa6" . . . 1
end
label values treatment_1 treatment_1_
label def treatment_1_ 1 "Observation", modify
label def treatment_1_ 2 "Afsluttet", modify
label values treatment_3 treatment_3_
label def treatment_3_ 1 "Observation", modify
label def treatment_3_ 2 "Afsluttet", modify
```

As you can see, in this example there are three different treatments and I have sorted the observations by the record_ID (patients). Notice that each patient (record_ID) can appear more than once. In fact I have expanded the dataset so if a patient has 4 aneurysms, there will be 4 observations as the statistics are based on aneurysms, not patients.

My problem is, it's seemingly random which one of these observations will describe which treatment each aneurysm got, and I would like to add a variable `treatment` that lists treatment for the corresponding aneurysm ID. Also note `treatmentChoice_` means "which treatment did aneurysm 1 get?" and `treatmentChoice_1` means "which treatment did aneurysm 2 get?"

Is there a way to perhaps say:

"For each record_ID that is identical, look through `treatmentChoice_` and set `treatment` to that value if aneurysm ID is 1. Then do the same for `treatmentChoice_1`, `treatmentChoice_3` and set `treatment` to their value if aneurysm ID is 2 or 3 respectively.

Comment: The numbering system seems awry here:  `treatmentChoice_` for aneurysm 1 and `treatmentChoice_1` for 2 and `treatmentChoice_2` for 3? If those are your names, it would be best to clean up promptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow this correctly you want to select one non-missing value from some variables in each observation. For that you can use `max()` or `min()` or the `rowmin()` or `rowmax()` function from `egen`.

With your example data (thanks), I got this. Note the two unlabelled values of 4.

```
. generate treatment = max(treatmentChoice_, treatment_1, treatment_3)
(73 missing values generated)

. label val treatment treatment_1_

. tab treatment

  treatment |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
Observation |         16       59.26       59.26
  Afsluttet |          9       33.33       92.59
          4 |          2        7.41      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |         27      100.00
```